# Issue with reusing AVPlayer instance for playing video

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

I am to play same video in two screens with keeping seek time. So that I am reusing `AVPlayer` instance in these screen. For first time `AVPlayer` works fine, but whenever it is reused frame of player animates from top-left to fit target view on start of play.

like,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ieb4bnb0rsn9ig/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif?dl=0

code looks like,

```
    if myObj._playerResult != nil {
        _player = myObj._playerResult //reuse player instance
    } else {
        // First create an AVPlayerItem
        let playerItem : AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string:sVideoUrl as String))
        _player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    }

    playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController?.showsPlaybackControls = false
    playerController?.player = _player
    playerController!.view.frame = targetView.bounds 
    targetView.addSubview(playerController!.view)       
    _player?.play()
```